# How do I check for null value in an excel userform textbox?

Tags: vba

Why does the following not work?

```
If IsNull(Me.TextBox1.Value) = True Then

MsgBox "Null"

Else

MsgBox "Not Null"

End If
```

Here, I don't enter any value in "TextBox1" but it still passes the first `if` loop and displays "Not Null"

How do I check for null values?

Comment: Is there a default value set for TextBox1?  Is it reading as a blank string instead of a null?

Comment: Yes, when I debug it displays "" when I hover over "TextBox1.Value"

Comment: "" is not the same as null, it is the same as vbNullString. Use Bruno Leite's solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
If me.textbox1= vbNullString then
```

[]'s

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Excel on my computer, but can you try `Me.TextBox1.Text` instead of `Me.TextBox1.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the default value of blank textbox is `""`

Try:

```
If (Me.TextBox1.Value) = "" Then 
   MsgBox "Null" 
Else 
  MsgBox "Not Null"  
End If
```

Lets see if it is working