# Make textbox null if empty

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

hello I have a userform in excel which is connected to mysql server.
everything works except when I leave the textbox for date empty, I get an error that the value for date is incorrect

on further research I found that the textbox return zero length string when empty and mysql allows only null.
Is there anyway to set the textbox as null when I click on the save button.

Comment: try the change or leave event

Comment: Maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475023/how-do-i-check-for-null-value-in-an-excel-userform-textbox/7475152#7475152

Answer (score 0):

Heres my attempt at a solution, hopefully this will help.

Basically its a quick check to see if the textbox in question is empty, and if so, then make it null:

```
If textbox1.value = "" then
    textbox1.value = null
end if
```

Comment: I thought about that, where should I add this code to..should I add it to the button click event??

Answer (score 0):

Finally a solution, but this will be a pain in the b, if you have 20 date columns. Unfortunately I have 20 date columns..:(

This is the code which for me, hope this helps someone in the future

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
```

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strCon = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;Database=sample;" _
& "User=root;Password=Password;Option=3;"

cn.Open strCon

If txt5.Value = "" Then

```
SQLStr = "insert into sample.details (ID,Name,Age,Gender,Date_of_Birth) values ('" & txt1.Value & "', '" & txt2.Value & "','" & txt3.Value & "','" & txt4.Value & "',Null);"

cn.Execute SQLStr
```

Else

```
SQLStr = "insert into sample.details (ID,Name,Age,Gender,Date_of_Birth) values ('" & txt1.Value & "', '" & txt2.Value & "','" & txt3.Value & "','" & txt4.Value & "','" & Format(txt5.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "');"

cn.Execute SQLStr
```

End If
End Sub